# Why this function doesn't calculate the working days right?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create a function named dbo.WorkingD which returns the working days for an given interval

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.WorkingD (@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TotalDays INT, @WorkDays INT

    SET @TotalDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1 
    SET @WorkDays = @TotalDays - (DATEDIFF(WEEK, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2) 

   --We exclude weekends (Saturday and Sunday)
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = 1  --Sunday
    SET @WorkDays = @WorkDays - 1
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @EndDate) = 7  -- Saturday
    SET @WorkDays = @WorkDays - 1
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = 7  
    SET @WorkDays = @WorkDays - 1
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @EndDate) = 1  
    SET @WorkDays = @WorkDays - 1

    RETURN @WorkDays
END;
```

Why for this example the output is 3 instead of 5:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2023-07-15'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2023-07-23'

SELECT dbo.WorkingD(@StartDate, @EndDate) AS numar_zile_lucratoare;
```

I've seen that if I keep only 2 IFs I get the right output, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Why would you reduce it twice for Saturday and Sunday???  Your query is saying if it is a Saturday or Sunday, `@Workdays = @Workdays - 2`.  Of course it won't give you the correct result.

Comment: It appears that @WorkDays is being set a value that subtracts all the weekend days between two dates. You then have further logic that will subtract additional days if the start and/or end date is a weekend day. This will result in skewed values if the start or end date happen to fall on weekend days.

Comment: You should likely just use a calendar table anyway so you can also take account of things like public holidays

Comment: You realize that `DATEDIFF(WEEK)` returns not the number of full 7-day weeks between the two days, but the number of times a week boundary was crossed? `datediff(week, '20230722', '20230723')` will return `1` (assuming your week starts on Sunday; otherwise try `datediff(week, '20230723', '20230724')`).

Comment: watch out for DATEPART(WEEKDAY), this stuff is non-deterministic and depends on set datefirst setting

Comment: See "How many workdays are in <this date range>?" in [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to begin using calendar-based functions frequently then I agree with what has been mentioned. Incorporating a simple calendar table to your database will reduce the complexity and increase the readability of your date-based functions. A generic example follows:

**Create and Build-up the CalendarTable**

```
-- Note: a @temp table is being used for this example
-- You could easily convert to a regular table

DECLARE @CalendarTable TABLE (DayOrder INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, CalendarDate DATETIME, IsWeekDay BIT)

DECLARE @CalendarStartDate DATETIME = '01/01/1980'
DECLARE @CalendarEndDate DATETIME = (SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, 10, GETDATE()) )    
DECLARE @DaysToAdd INT = DATEDIFF(DAY,@CalendarStartDate, @CalendarEndDate)

;WITH R1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
R2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM R1 a, R1 b),
R3(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM R2 a, R2 b),
R4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM R3 a, R3 b),
Tally(Number) AS (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM R4)

INSERT INTO @CalendarTable
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, Number, @CalendarStartDate),
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, Number, @CalendarStartDate)) IN(1,7) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM
    Tally
WHERE
    Number < @DaysToAdd
```

**Redefine Function Using CalendarTable**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.WorkingD (@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
   
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN IsWeekDay = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        FROM 
           CalendarTable
        WHERE
           CalendarDate >= @StartDate AND CalendarDate <= @EndDate  

    )
 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

My view for my example:

```
SET @TotalDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1 -- 23-15+1=9 days
SET @WorkDays = @TotalDays - (DATEDIFF(WEEK, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)-- 9-1*2=7 subtract de weekend (because in 9 days i have only 1 full week)

IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = 1  -- now in my example the interval begins on Saturday and ends in Sunday which I should subtract
    SET @WorkDays = @WorkDays - 1
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @EndDate) = 7  
    SET @WorkDays = @WorkDays - 1
```

**Am I right? Or have any of you other ideas for another algorithm?**

Comment: -- now in my example the interval begins on Saturday and ends in Sunday which I should subtract - True, however, you have already subtracted this from the last full week in the range, in an earlier operation.

Comment: The 2 days subtracted from the 2nd line It will be 16 (Sunday ) and 22 (Saturday )

Comment: because in this range I have 4 weekends and only one full week

Comment: What happens when you set the start date to 2023-07-08 or 2022-01-01?